# What is the proper way to find the connection ID by the requested query statement in TiDB?

Tags: pid, tidb, processlist

Im creating an alter automation script that executes an alter on the TiDB cluster. In case of an error, I need to kill the running alter using the `KILL` statement - https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/sql-statement-kill.

`KILL` requires a connection ID as an input. The only way to get this connection is to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CLUSTER_PROCESSLIST` table (https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/information-schema-processlist#cluster_processlist) and get find the connection by INFO column (this column has requested query). But TiDB does some formatting before it inserts the query into the `INFO` column. For example, it removes all comments and probably does something else. So searching by the `INFO` column might be problematic as I don't know what exact formatting TiDB does.

How can I find the connection ID from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CLUSTER_PROCESSLIST` by the raw query? Is it possible to normalize the input query in the same manner as TiDB does and query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CLUSTER_PROCESSLIST` as follows:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CLUSTER_PROCESSLIST` 
WHERE INFO = NORMALIZE('/*comment*/ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN c') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Or perhaps there is any other way around how I can get the connection ID of an ongoing query so I can kill it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the sql digest first and query the process ID by digest in `CLUSTER_PROCESSLIST` table.

> The "SQL digest" here means the same as used in slow logs, which is a unique identifier calculated through normalized SQL statements. The normalization process ignores constant, blank characters, and is case insensitive. Therefore, statements with consistent syntaxes have the same digest.

https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/dev/statement-summary-tables#statements_summary

If you use Golang for programing, you can use the tidb-parser get the digest for your SQL.

https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/blob/master/parser/docs/quickstart.md

go.mod:

```
go 1.18

require github.com/pingcap/tidb/parser v0.0.0-20220923141543-ecd67531f172
```

example.go:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pingcap/tidb/parser"
    "github.com/pingcap/tidb/parser/ast"
    _ "github.com/pingcap/tidb/parser/test_driver"
)

sql := "SELECT * FROM github_events;"
normalized, digest := parser.NormalizeDigest(sql)
```

If you use Node.js, maybe you can use [tidb-sql-parser](https://github.com/634750802/tidb-sql-parser), which is use wasm to build.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to cancel a DDL statement? Kill statement usually use to kill the DML statements. You can refer to Max's reply to get the ID to kill a DML statement.

if you want to Kill a DDL statement, you should use "ADMIN CANCEL DDL" statement: https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/sql-statement-admin-cancel-ddl#admin-cancel-ddl, this syntax is unique to TiDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I need to use it for both DDL and DML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement to get a list of all currently active client connections. OR get from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`.

Here is an example(`ID` is the connection ID that you are looking for):

```
mysql> SELECT ID, USER, HOST, DB, COMMAND, TIME, STATE, INFO FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST;
```

You can also use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` table in a `WHERE` clause to filter the list of connections.

Comment: Thanks, i know the process more or less. The problem is in detail - how to find the exact row in the `PROCESSLIST` table based on the raw SQL statement that I have.